# QGIS printing acting REALLY strange

Tags: qgis, printing, maps

[image]

I'm printing a 11 x 17 map but the QGIS print properties are acting weird. For instance , i set my composition presets to ANSI B (11x 17 in.) and the page setup to 11 x 17 but it prints off a 11 x 17 but only with the print composer wedged in the upper left hand corner. it should just fit to the whole page like my presets suggest.

Any advice? i am stumped.

Comment: What operating system are you using? What does the print window look like? Can you export as a vector PDF first and see if it comes out right?

Comment: look at above picture- do my settings look right?  Using Windows 10.

Comment: change 'cached' to 'render' in the main properties.

Comment: @GregJones the composer window looks right- can you check an exported PDF and what the operating system print dialogue looks like?

Comment: print dialogue states that the page size is 11 x 17 and the output size is 11 x 17 .

Comment: Is the print dialog set to portrait orientation?

Answer (score 1):

figured it out. turns out i wasn't saving when i made it a 11 x 17 map so the map was just taking the unsaved map to print.

Comment: This still seems like unusual behavior. A print composer set to 11x17 should print as 11x17 regardless of whether you've saved the QGIS project file.